# SOSL does not find numeric fields

Tags: query, sosl

We have the following SOSL query to find financial transactions:

> List> searchList = [FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS
>   RETURNING Financial_Transactions__c (Financial_Account__r.Nickname__c,
>   Financial_Account__r.Name, Transaction_Date__c,
>   Merchant_Name__c,Original_Description__c,
>   Date__c,Security_Symbol__c,Category__c,Transaction_Type__c,Quantity__c,Price__c,Amount__c
>   where (Financial_Account__c=:mappingOfValues.get('id') and
>   Financial_Account__r.Status__c NOT IN ('Pending Delete') and
>   Date__c>=:fromDate and Date__c <=:toDate) ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT
>   500 OFFSET :offSetCalc)];

It would return amounts of $233, $2343, $5656 for respective records. When I search for any of the amounts nothing gets returned. And I did specify IN ALL FIELDS in my SOQL query so it should be returning those records.

Is it because SOSL does not search on numeric fields?What would be a way to solve this?

Comment: Why not just use SOQL?

Comment: "ALL" is a bit deceptive. It means "search all fields that can be searched," not "search every field in every object", which is different. This is in contrast to things like "NAME" that searches just name fields, etc. The answer provided is correct; you'd have to put your numbers into a text field somewhere if you wanted to use SOSL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct. Per the [Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_about.htm), SOSL is for "text-based search queries". On the [FIND page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm), it also says in many ways that it is for words or phrases.

If you have a number inside of a text field, it does work. Example "I want 6000 pizzas delivered" in a comment field of type textarea. `find {6000} in all fields returning Object__c (comment__c)` will hit on that.